# How can I get log of the android app running on real device which uses its SD card?

Tags: android, testing, android-sdcard

I have Samsung Galaxy Ace, Android version: 2.2.1.

My app uses the camera and gallery, which require SD card to be mounted. But in the USB mode, the SD card is not detected because of which I am not able to test the app. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why is the SD not detected?  You must be automatically mounting the SD card when plugging in your USB cable.  Check your notification to make sure not to mount it as a disk drive

Comment: I'm a bit confused by a question. Do you need to dump `LogCat` logs when your devices sdcard is mounted via `USB`?

Comment: are you unmounting your sdcard for your usb connection? you shouldnt have to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep hooraygradschool's answer is correct: you do not need to u'Turn on USB-Storage' when connecting your device to a pc when working in Eclipse or other ADB-related stuff.

Just hook up your phone with your pc - maybe check if it didn't turn usbstorage on automatically? this could be your problem.. (good one John :)

Then fire up Eclipse.

(Actually, you can start Eclipse prior to connecting your device)

Another solution: try LogViewer from the market (although I wouldn't recommend using it for development when it's not absolutely required to have your phone unplugged from power)

Hope my english is okay :)